# Pandas merge on nested columns if one column's entry is contained in the other

Tags: pandas, join, merge

I want to create a function `new_merge`, which is a pandas merge with all the usual rules for the `left_on` and `right_on` columns, but with some additional logic. There will be 2 additional list parameters (both specifying some column(s)) for this - let's call them `left_partial_on` and `right_partial_on`. 2 entries of the 2 separate columns `left_partial_on[i][j]`, `right_partial_on[i][k]` are considered to 'match' only when every element of `left_partial_on[i][j]` is contained in `right_partial_on[i][k]` OR vice versa (i.e. every element of `right_partial_on[i][j]` is contained in `left_partial_on[i][k]`).

So for example, suppose I have these data frames

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Writer': [['John', 'Adam'], ['Gary', 'Peter'], ['Frida', 'Kate']], 'Cast': [['Carrie', 'Ryan'], ['Jamie'], ['Maggie', 'Shaun']], 'Title': ['The Boring Film', 'The Great Film', 'The Awesome Film']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Writer': [['Adam', 'John'], ['Betty', 'Bob'], ['Frida']], 'Cast': [['Carrie', 'Rita'], ['Paula', 'Beatrice'], ['Maggie']], 'Title': ['The Boring Film', 'The Great Film', 'The Awesome Film'], 'val': [1, 2, 3]})
```

then when I call `new_merge(df1, df2, left_on = ['Title'], right_on = ['Title'], left_partial_on = ['Writer', 'Cast'], right_partial_on = ['Writer', 'Cast'], how = 'inner')` I end up with just the final row:

```
Writer  Cast        Title             val
[Frida] [Maggie]    The Awesome Film  3
```

Explanation: the only possible matches between the data frames are both of the first, second, and third rows, since otherwise `Title` is not equal between the 2. For the 1st row, each of `[Adam, John]` is contained in `[John, Adam]` so `Writer` is a match, but `Ryan` is not contained within `[Carrie, Rita]` so `Cast` is not a match. Similarly, in the 2nd row, `Jamie` is not contained in `[Paula, Beatrice]` so `Cast` is not a match in the 2nd row either. But the 3rd  `[Frida, Kate]` contains every element in `[Frida]`, `[Maggie, Shaun]` contains every element in `[Maggie]`, and as we have established the `Title` is equal, hence we have a match.

Similarly, if I was to just change the parameter `how` and call `new_merge(df1, df2, left_on = ['Title'], right_on = ['Title'], left_partial_on = ['Writer', 'Cast'], right_partial_on = ['Writer', 'Cast'], how = 'right')` I end up with:

```
Writer         Cast              Title             val
[Adam, John]   [Carrie, Rita]    The Boring Film
[Betty, Bob]   [Paula, Beatrice] The Great Film    
[Frida]        [Maggie]          The Awesome Film  3
```

When it comes to packaging this up as a function, all I could think to try was something for-loop based and hence very slow, because I am working with very large data frames (not just this example). I am a bit stumped for what would be a more/the most efficient way to do this. I have looked for implementations on here and whether or not there are existing functions in pandas that do this, but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible solution. First, explode all the columns in `left_partial_on` and `right_partial_on`. Then count the rows for each film. Now merge the two dataframes together on *all* the columns, and count the number of rows for each film in the result. If that count matches the count from the either dataframe, keep the film in the result. Finally, re-aggregate the "partial" fields back into lists.

```py
def new_merge(df1, df2, left_on, right_on, left_partial_on, right_partial_on, how='inner'):
    
    def explode_partials(df, cols):
        dfe = df.explode(cols[0])
        for col in cols[1:]:
            dfe = dfe.explode(col)
        return dfe
    
    df1e = explode_partials(df1, left_partial_on)
    df2e = explode_partials(df2, right_partial_on)
    
    df1e['rows'] = df1e.groupby(left_on).transform('size')
    df2e['rows'] = df2e.groupby(right_on).transform('size')
    
    merged = df1e.merge(df2e, left_on=left_on + left_partial_on, right_on=right_on + right_partial_on, how=how)
    
    group_cols = list(set(left_on + right_on))
    mergedsizes = merged.groupby(group_cols).transform('size')
    
    merged = merged[(merged['rows_x'] == mergedsizes) | (merged['rows_y'] == mergedsizes)]
    merged = merged.drop(columns=['rows_x', 'rows_y'])
    
    return merged.groupby(group_cols, sort=False).agg(lambda g:list(set(g.dropna()))).reset_index()

new_merge(df1, df2, ['Title'], ['Title'], ['Writer', 'Cast'], ['Writer', 'Cast'])
```

Output:

```
              Title   Writer      Cast
0  The Awesome Film  [Frida]  [Maggie]
```

Another example:

```
df3 = df2.copy()
df3.loc[0, 'Cast'] = df1.loc[0, 'Cast']
new_merge(df3, df1, ['Title'], ['Title'], ['Writer', 'Cast'], ['Writer', 'Cast'])
```

Output:

```
              Title        Writer            Cast
0   The Boring Film  [Adam, John]  [Carrie, Ryan]
1  The Awesome Film       [Frida]        [Maggie]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This seems to run relatively quickly, nonetheless I was hoping for the function to work regardless of the type of merge - e.g. for it to also be able to do a left merge if specified. Apologies if this was unclear in my original question and I have made some edits to the examples to make this clearer.

Comment: @ElisEvans sorry, I did just try to solve the problem in the question. It's late here, but I'll take another look in the morning.

Comment: @ElisEvans I've looked at this again and made some changes to support left and right merges. It's a bit tricky to deal with the extra values as it's not clear when they should be kept. Have a play and see what you think

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is close to what I need but I noticed an edge case for duplicated left/right_on column(s). E.g. if I add the rows

`[Gary] | [Jamie] | The Great Film` to `df1`, and `[Gary] | [Jamie, Paulo] | The Great Film | 3` to `df2`

then `new_merge(df1, df2, ['Title'], ['Title'], ['Writer', 'Cast'], ['Writer', 'Cast'], how = 'right')` drops both of the rows of `df2` where `Title` is `The Great Film`

Comment: That's pretty tricky to work around. Can you maybe aggregate the duplicates by doing something like `df2.groupby('Title').agg({ 'Writer' : unique_list, 'Cast' : unique_list, 'val' : 'first' })` where `unique_list = lambda g:list(set(g.sum()))`?